# Cor padrão de app

Tags: android, android-layout

Olá,

Preciso localizar como setar a cor padrão dos aplicativos. Não seria a cor de background ou de fonte, seria a cor do app mesmo.

Por exemplo: em configurações de led, tem a opção de mostrar o led de acordo com a cor do app( whats app verde, facebook azul, etc).

Como setar essa cor programaticamente?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você está se referindo a cor do toolbar ? Se for isso, você pode altera-las no arquivo colors.xml na pasta de nome values, lá você encontrará <color name="colorPrimary">#ff8e2b</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff7700</color> é só substituir o hexadecimal pelo o da cor que você quer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No teu manifest.xml você precisa mudar o nome do seu tema. pode escolher outros temas existentes ou criar o seu próprio em colors.xml.